# 'q' parameter for opt_param in listDrafts using php

Tags: php, api, gmail

I am integrating the Gmail API with PHP.  I created a search box in the **inbox** label; this works perfectly. When I do the same in the **Draft** label, I get the error

```
(list): unknown parameter 'q'
```

This is the code i have used

```
function listDrafts($service, $userId,$mes) {

  $drafts = array();

 $opt_param =array();
 $opt_param['q'] = $mes;

  try {

    $draftsResponse = $service->users_drafts->listUsersDrafts($userId,$opt_param);

    if ($draftsResponse->getDrafts()) {

      $drafts = array_merge($drafts, $draftsResponse->getDrafts());

    }

  } catch (Exception $e) {

    print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();

  }
```

Does the Gmail API in PHP support the **listDrafts** 'q' parameter?

Comment: You should provide the part of code you are talking about to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: According to the reference (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list) it should be supported. Post the relevant code parts of your implementation.

Comment: Improve wording; fix typos

Comment: In gmail.php  there is  no parameter 'q' in list drafts function/**
   * Lists the drafts in the user's mailbox. (drafts.listUsersDrafts)
   * param string $userId The user's email address. The special value me can be
   * used to indicate the authenticated user.
   * param array $optParams Optional parameters.
   *
   * opt_param string maxResults Maximum number of drafts to return.
   * opt_param string pageToken Page token to retrieve a specific page of results
   * in the list.
   * return Google_Service_Gmail_ListDraftsResponse
   */

Answer (score 0):

**Does the Gmail API in PHP support the listDrafts 'q' parameter?**

Yes, it does. Check the [Gmail API reference.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list)

But the [Google API PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) does not support the "q" parameter for `listUsersDrafts` method yet.

Until it does, you can edit the Gmail.php located in `google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Gmail.php`.

You have to find the below code block in the above file:

```
$this->users_drafts = new Google_Service_Gmail_UsersDrafts_Resource(
    .
    .
    .
    .
        ,'list' => array(
          'path' => '{userId}/drafts',
          'httpMethod' => 'GET',
          'parameters' => array(
            'userId' => array(
              'location' => 'path',
              'type' => 'string',
              'required' => true,
            ),
            'maxResults' => array(
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'integer',
            ),
            'pageToken' => array(
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'string',
            )
          ),
        )
    .
    .
    .
```

Then change it as shown below (added the q to the parameters array).

```
.
    .
    .
        ,'list' => array(
          'path' => '{userId}/drafts',
          'httpMethod' => 'GET',
          'parameters' => array(
            'userId' => array(
              'location' => 'path',
              'type' => 'string',
              'required' => true,
            ),
            'maxResults' => array(
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'integer',
            ),
            'pageToken' => array(
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'string',
            ),
            'q' => array(
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'string',
            )
          ),
        )
    .
    .
    .
```

But I do not recommended to do this. I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/pull/1062) and added a new issue in GitHub. Hopefully they will add this soon. You can use it after they add it. I wrote a [post here](http://bitmapcake.blogspot.com/2016/09/q-parameter-error-for-listusersdrafts.html) about this issue.